# Как перебрать все элементы с определенным названием JSON Python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Структура моего JSON:

```
{"name": {"code": "6kkUEC6XA", "invites": 0}, "name2": {"code": "HTTPsC5IX", "invites": 0}, "name3": {"code": "Z26U6AE2B", "invites": 0}}
```

Мне нужно сравнить значение каждого элемента "code" с аргументом команды.

Я пробовал сделать это через цикл:

```
@bot.command()
async def c(ctx, *, code):
    with open('referal.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        ref = json.load(f)

    for i in ref["code"]:
        if code == ref[i]['code']:
            await print("YES")

        else:
            await print("NO")
```

Получаю ошибку об исключении:

```
Ignoring exception in command c:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HTTPs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
s\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 489, in c
    for i in ref["code"]:
KeyError: 'code'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HTTPs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
s\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HTTPs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
s\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HTTPs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
s\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Ke
Error: 'code'
```

Структуры JSON я изменить не могу, и других способов я не вижу.
Как можно сделать такой перебор элементов?

Comment: Просто `for i in ref:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас была ошибка в `for i in ref["code"]:`

```py
jsonFile = {
    "name": {
        "code": "6kkUEC6XA",
        "invites": 0
    },
    "name2": {
        "code": "HTTPsC5IX",
        "invites": 0
    },
    "name3": {
        "code": "Z26U6AE2B",
        "invites": 0
    }
}
dict1 = jsonFile.items()
for item in dict1:
    if item[1]['code'] == 'Z26U6AE2B':
        yield item[1]
```

p.s. всегда дебажте свой код